# Change default font and fontsize in pdf using itextsharp

Tags: itext

How do I set the default font and font size for a PDF document using iIextSharp so that it is used throughout the PDF.

Comment: According to your comment below you are saying something about HTML, please explain this more. Are you parsing HTML? If so, then in that case you can actually specify a default font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer guys but i sorted out the problem by just overriding the default font of XmlWorker by taking the font from the external CSS:

```
public static void ParseHtmlToPdf(IElementHandler handler,StringReader inputText,float maxWidth,float maxHeight)
    {
        XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider();
        fontProvider.Register(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/IMTLayout/IMTFonts/CenturyGothic/GOTHIC.TTF"), "Default_CenturyGothic");
        CssAppliers ca = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
        var context = new HtmlPipelineContext(ca);
        context.SetAcceptUnknown(true);
        context.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        context.SetImageProvider(new CustomImageHandler { BaseUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(),MaxHeight = maxHeight,MaxWidth = maxWidth});
        var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
        cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/IMTLayout/IMTCss/pdfreport.css"), true);
        var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
                                               new HtmlPipeline(context, new ElementHandlerPipeline(handler, null)));
        var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
        var parser = new XMLParser();
        parser.AddListener(worker);
        parser.Parse(inputText);
    }
```

And my CSS file has the following properties:

```
strong b {font-weight:bold;font-family:Century Gothic;}
em i {font-style:italic;font-family:Century Gothic;}
p,ol,ul,li,dl,a,td,tr{font-family:Century Gothic;font-size:10pt;color:#191919;}
a{color:Blue;}
td,tr,table{border-width:0.5px;}
```

Comment: If you wonder why noone else stepped forward and answered your question with that idea... Well, try and show where in your question you mentioned working with html and the `XmlWorker` while trying to create pdfs with iTextSharp.

Answer (score 3):

Met the same issue with Russian and Romanian alphabets(`itextsharp 5.5.6.0, .net 3.5`). I've just added:

```
string arialuniTff = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF");
FontFactory.Register(arialuniTff);    
StyleSheet ST = new StyleSheet();
ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Arial Unicode MS");
ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H)
```

and

```
parser.SetStyleSheet(ST);
```

but before you start parsing your TextReader add:

```
parser.Parse(reader);
```

Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following function (you can change the font style/size as you desire)

```
Private Function FormatPhrase(value As String) As Phrase
    Return New Phrase(value, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8))
End Function
```

And use this to display the information. For example,

```
Dim stuName As PdfPCell = New PdfPCell(FormatPhrase("Sample Document"))
```

Comment: This is correct, but I just want to elaborate. iText doesn't support setting a "default font" for a document and instead you need manually specify it each time. As @Aishvarya points out, this can be made slightly easier by helper/factory methods.

Comment: As this is not what i want because i know this thing already but my real problem is that when i change the font then my html format of the text are all gone which i don't want to happen. Any help is admirable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);


Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Some text content here \n", font));
```